# Run scoring-process without needing to load packages/models/datasets every time

Tags: r, environment, preload, rserve

it's certainly possible that this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find it so here I go...

I've built an R-scoringprocess which consists off some ETL and then a scoring with existing models. My client first wanted to use this as a webservice, so I was going to use the opencpu-server for that and everything seemed fine. However, suddenly the client thinks this package (the webservice) might pose a security-issue. So now the process must be changed to:

- client drops file on server
- new file automatically gets detected and R scoring-process is started
- result of scoring is dropped somewhere on server

Thing is, I use several packages and several models (which I created). It will take way too much time to load these in the environment every time the scoringprocess is called for (client wants to make lots of calls and each scoring is for '1 record'). Is there a way I can start R with packages/models/some data loaded in the environment, and then have my OS detect a new file and run the R-process through that environment (so packages, models and data don't have to be loaded)?

I've been researching this, but I couldn't really find how it supposed to be done, so any input would be very welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about packages, but you can save/load your environment to a .rda file. Check `?save` for more information

Comment: Yes indeed, I was thinking in that direction. But what I have to figure out is how I could have that environment 'online' so te speak, so I could run my scoringprocess time and again without ever having to reload models and packages in the environment...

Comment: You can try `Rserve`. Rserve 'spawns' R processes, each with their own environment. Rserve processes can run on a server for years, this includes their own same environment. You can have a look [here](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/). It's either that or load an `.rda` file each time, the last one being somewhat easier.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answers. So this makes it possible to sart an 'Rserve-process' (in which my models/packages/functions) are loaded.

And then do 'R CMD BATCH scoring_process.R' using the process 'spawned' by Rserve? Do I do this using some kind of parameter (indicating that I want to use the Rserve process) in the R CMD BATCH - command? 

Thanks again, you've been a great help already!

edit: Maybe this is something I could use? http://www.rforge.net/RSclient/git.html

Comment: In theory, yes that should be possible. I do not know the exact commands, and it all depends on your project. Connect to a Rserve process with [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSclient/index.html), [Java](http://codophile.com/2015/05/02/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rserve/), or [C#](https://github.com/konne/RserveCLI2)

Comment: Allright, will check this out further, thank you very much, your help is really appreciated...